# Why does my terminal show % instead of $? (macOS Big Sur)

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm starting to learn python and I've been having to use my terminal a bit; however, all tutorials I have found online show the login info and input symbol as `user-macbook:~name$`, as well as inserting $ for running commands. However, my terminal displays `user@Macbook-Air ~ %`, and the usage of $ is not computed. What could be wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with „the usage of $ is not computed“?

Answer (score 7):

I can't find an accepted answer to dupe this to, and since it's always been answered in comments, I'm going to make it a real answer so we can point people here. (Yes, it should be on Ask Different, but it gets asked here a lot.)

See [macOS different Prompt meaning `%` vs `$`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65405994) and [Updated my shell to zsh, command prompt now ends in a %](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59637422) for a couple of recent versions.

You've switched from bash to zsh (this became the new default in 10.15), and zsh has a different default prompt. The commands you find online will still be fine. You don't type the leading `$`. That's just indicating where the prompt is (and in zsh it's `%`).

If you wish to switch back to bash, use the following command to change your default shell:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: There is no automatic switching to zsh. Accounts which were using bash stayed on bash after the upgrade.

Comment: @nohillside But it is true that new accounts and new Macs will use zsh by default.

Comment: Rob, you could mention that the prompt is totally configurable (but leave how to as an exercise for the inquiring mind).